# A proof of recontruction of Sacks generic filter from it's Sacks real (M[G] = M[f])

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Given the Sacks forcing $ (\mathbb{S} = \{T \subset 2^{<\omega} : T \text{ is perfect}\},\subset) $ and $G$ generic over M, we have $f = \bigcup \bigcap G = \bigcup_{T \in G}stem(G) $ a path through all of the trees in $G$.

Given $f$ we can set $ G_f = \{ T \in \mathbb{S} : f \in [T] \} $. Most of my sources state $G_f = G$ but I'm struggling to understand the proof of $G_f \subset G$, when present.

Comment: I wrote a technical report proving this without using fusion some years ago. You can find it here: https://www.cle.unicamp.br/eprints/index.php/CLE_e-Prints/issue/view/181

Comment: If you believe that $G \subseteq G_f$, then you can just use the fact that generic filters are maximal.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f \in [T]$. $D = \{ S : S \leq T \vee S \perp T \}$ is dense, so let $S \in D \cap G$. If $S \leq T$, then we are fine. So we have to shoot down $S \perp T$. By Cantor-Bendixson, it suffices to prove that in the ground model $V$, $[S] \cap [T]$ is uncountable. To see this, let $\{ x_n : n<\omega \} \in V$ be your favorite ctble. set of reals in $V$. In $V[G]$, $f \in ([S] \cap [T]) \setminus \{ x_n : n<\omega \}$, and hence by Shoenfield (we just need $\Sigma^1_1$ absoluteness), in $V$ there is some real in $([S] \cap [T]) \setminus \{ x_n : n<\omega \}$, as desired.